# Keyboard shortcuts for TexMaker's built-in pdf viewer

Tags: texmaker, viewers

I'd like to navigate in a pdf with TexMaker's built-in viewer, and define custom keyboard shortcuts for such a navigation. Where can I find the preferences of the built-in pdf viewer ? I don't even know how to go back and forth in the pdf viewer, which is typically useful after clicking on a reference hyperlink. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Some hints are, on my Mac the "command" + "left" or "right" arrow keys rotate the pdf file. Right click on the pdf document itself opens some limited options like word counts and the "command + left click" option that aligns the source text to the pdf file position. To go backwards to the pdf position after a link, my fix is to leave the source text in its current position, click the hyperlink in the pdf document, then click the right arrow (view), which is positioned to the left of the pdf view button to realign the pdf document to the source text position.

Comment: What do you mean by *navigate in the pdf* and *go back and forth* ? You can navigate the pdf with your keyboard arrows and page up/down ...